# Extract <header> with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

How to extract all the `<header></header>` from a page with Scrapy?
I tried this, but to no avail: `response.css('header')`

Also, I need all of `<img></img>` from `<header></header>` itself to analyze the `class` content and the `src` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
response.xpath('//header')
```

For the images:

```
response.xpath('//header//img') # This assumes there are img tags somewhere inside header
```

Add `@class` to the selector so it returns the class value and `@src` for the src value.

Comment: Thanks renatodvc! It's possible extract the absolut `src`, with the `https://`? Some links don't return the complete link, only a part, eg.: `/images/logo_site.png` and not this: `https://example.com/images/logo_site.png`

Comment: You extract them as they are in the source. When they are relative path is your browser that adjust them to a full path. You can use `response.urljoin(extracted_url)` to get the abs path.